# Get all git commits since last tag

Tags: git, version-control

When I'm going to tag a commit, I need to know what changed since the last tagged commit. Eg:

```
a87a6sdf87a6d4 Some new feature
a87a6sdf87a6d3 Some bug fix
a87a6sdf87a6d2 Some comments added
a87a6sdf87a6d1 Some merge <- v1.4.0
```

In this example I would like to know about the 3 newest commits, or be able to print a log like above, that shows both commits their tags if any. And when I see there has been a new feature added, I would tag it v1.5.0.

How do you deal with this? Is this how I'm supposed to use tags? What should I write in the tag message? I always leave it blank: `git tag -a v1.2.3 -m ''`

Comment: I know this was an old question, but what operating system was you interested about? Somebody replied mentionig Windows about first answer, for example. Are you using Linux? Maybe nice to clarify in the question that you want a system-independent solution or something like that

Answer (score 327, accepted):

```
git log <yourlasttag>..HEAD
```

If you want them like in your example, on the one line with commit id + message, then

```
git log <yourlasttag>..HEAD --oneline
```

and in case you don't know your latest tag or want this to be dynamic, on Linux / git bash / Windows bash you could do:

```
git log $(git describe --tags --abbrev=0)..HEAD --oneline
```

and on Windows:

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('git describe --tags --abbrev^=0') do @set latesttag=%a
git log %latesttag%..HEAD --oneline
```

Also, if you have a case where you know a tag in history and want to print everything from that tag up to current situation, you might want to add also `--decorate` so it would print out any tags in between.

Comment: `--oneline` should be before `<yourlasttag>..HEAD`. Also, `@` is short for `HEAD`. Using `$()` may be preferable to using backticks.

Comment: @A-B-B there is no difference if `--oneline` is before or after. I would also prefer HEAD even if there is a shorthand, as it is easier to understand and more widely known.

Comment: and I see no benefit in using `$()` in this context. Maybe you have thought of some.

Comment: ok, it seems resources such as [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) find several reasons in using braces instead of backticks, so could change to use those

Comment: Is there a concise one-liner which can also handle cases where there may be no prior tag on the branch? It should just default to outputting the entire commit history for the branch.

Comment: The best I have currently is `last_tag=$(git describe --tags --abbrev=0); git log $(if [[ -z $last_tag ]]; then echo HEAD; else echo $last_tag..HEAD; fi) --pretty=format:"- %s"` but I'm sure this can be improved upon!

Comment: @JonathanEllis maybe you could raise that as a new question?

Comment: In Powershell, wrap the git log argument in quotes: `git log "$(git describe --tags --abbrev=0)..HEAD" --oneline`

Comment: Since the Linux version also works on Git for Windows Bash, I tried to mention that as first option, also since it's simpler. Also I flagged as outdated some comments that were saying "I don't know" or other things already integrated. Then feel free to nuke my comment too.

Answer (score 68):

If your current commit is also a tag and you want to dynamically get the changes since the previous tag, without knowing the latest tag nor previous tag name, you can do:

```
git log --oneline $(git describe --tags --abbrev=0 @^)..@
```

Note that `@` is short for `HEAD`.

Comment: nice!, if just want the commits text change --oneline to --pretty=format:"%s": git log --pretty=format:"%s" $(git describe --tags --abbrev=0 @^)..@

Answer (score 2):

You can easily omit Merge commits with sed

```
git log $(git describe --tags --abbrev=0)..@ --oneline | sed '/Merge/d'
```

Comment: Note that there is a dedicated option to do that and it's called `--no-merges`.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12083016/7075416), to omit merge commits, one can use

```
git log <tag>..HEAD --oneline --no-merges
```

as mentioned in this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35946023/7075416)