# How do I list all commits since the last subversion tag?

Tags: svn

I have an SVN repository with the following structure:

```
trunk/
tags/
    1.0.1/
    1.0.2/
    1.0.3/
```

How do I list all the commits that have happened on trunk since the last tag?

Comment: There's an answer for that question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12082981/how-to-get-all-commits-since-last-tag

Comment: @orbrey that's for git as far as I can see.

Comment: Gah! Serves me right for not reading properly, sorry about that. On the hunt now.

Comment: Okay... `svn log URL/tags --limit 1` will show you the latest tag and it's associated revision (X for the sake of this comment). Then you can do `svn log -r X:HEAD` to list all the commits since then.

Comment: @orbrey feel free to submit an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`svn log URL/tags --limit 1` will show you the latest tag and its associated revision (X for the sake of this comment). Then you can do `svn log -r X:HEAD` to list all the commits since then.